# Deflating objects in specs2 (scala) and checking order of elements in sequence

Tags: scala, specs2

Trying to write a small test case for already written code. Quiet new to Scala.

I have a service returning object like in `result` val

```
scala.util.Either[Error,Seq[Employee]]
```

I want to write a test case using specs2 which can make sure that the order of `Employee` sequence is exactly in the same order as my test data.

Order of my test data is like this:

```
val fakeEmployee: Seq[Employee] = Seq(
      Employee("first", "Simon"),
      Employee("second", "Ajay"),
      Employee("third", "Xavior")
)
```

What is the best way to deflate this object to get the `Sequence` object out and then check if sequence has objects in same order as `fakeEmployee`
something like this.

```
result.map {
   **Seq(Employee) must contain(allOf(".......").inOrder)**
}
```

Comment: Are you accepting also more data in the `result`? Or `allOf` means exact same data?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
val expected: Seq[Employee] = Seq(
  Employee("first", "Simon"),
  Employee("second", "Ajay"),
  Employee("third", "Xavior")
)

val result: Either[Error, Seq[Employee]] = ???

result must beRight(expected)
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, this worked for me. However {beEqualTo(expected)} also worked.